# Files to commit to repository in a Yeoman project

Tags: mercurial, yeoman

when you generate a yeoman project, do you commit the node_modules that is generated into your code repository?

It seems like it is necessary for another developer to check out a project and develop from it, but it seems like a lot of files to commit which seem unrelated to a project itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run `npm install` to get the dependencies installed. However there are multiple benefits to committing your dependencies, which you can read about in this blog post:

[Checking in front-end dependencies](http://addyosmani.com/blog/checking-in-front-end-dependencies/) *(for Bower, but applies to npm too)*